# Multipart/related API request using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

How to copy a pdf file content into a variable and then upload it as a multipart/related API request using JMeter??

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the file inline or save it into a JMeter Variable people normally use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) however it might not work for PDF files because they're binary so you might want to additionally convert it into [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), the [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup)  can be found in **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle which in its turn can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

In general I would suggest recording your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just remember to copy the PDF file you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation otherwise JMeter will fail to capture the request properly.